# What is the status of latex2html?

Tags: latex2html

Does anyone know the status of latex2html? I know that there are similar programs for that task, but I ask specifically about this one.

The [CTAN dir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex2html) lists a revision from 2002 and 2008, the http://latex2html.org website has broken links. Is the 2008 release the one to be used? Is there any development activity?

Comment: I stopped caring about latex2html when I discovered tex4ht.

Comment: @Herbert: Could you post your comment as answer so that this question can be concluded. Thanks!

Comment: We should not get über-organized. Every visitor sees the comments and knows the answers, so there is no reason to double the work and post the same twice.

Comment: @Patrick: Until there is an answer, this question remains on the unanswered list. This only makes it harder to find real unanswered questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no active development.