# Compile HTML from tex file

Tags: latex2html

I have installed TexMaker 3.1 on Windows 7. I can compile in pdf without problem. I would try to compile in HTML, what can I do? If I try to gave directly `latex2html %.tex` I get `Error : could not start the command`.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you use a `%` sign in the file name, or is that a typo?

Comment: According to [What is the status of latex2html?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22614/what-is-the-status-of-latex2html), `latex2html` is no longer om active development. Perhaps you should consider [tex4ht](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html).

Comment: i get `xhlatex %.tex` and process seems so long, it's normal?

Comment: is a typo, for the name file without extension.

Comment: Process is starded 57 mins ago and is still running O_o

Comment: Perhaps you should try running `xhlatex` on a simpler file.  If that works, then you know there is some problem with your own `.tex` file (from `tex4ht`'s pespective, at least).  I find, for instance, that it is better to use `tex4ht` without `hyperref` loaded.  What you will need to do is create a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528), and then edit your original question to include this example file for others to examine.  As it is, your question is too vague for anyone to answer unless you get lucky.